# String.format() throws FormatFlagsConversionMismatchException

Tags: java, string, string-formatting, java-7

This code works fine in Java 1.6:

```
 public static String padLeft(String s, int n)
 {
     if (n <= 0)
         return s;
     int noOfSpaces = n * 2;
     String output;
     noOfSpaces = s.length() + noOfSpaces;
     output = String.format("%1$#" + noOfSpaces + "s", s);
     return output;
 }
```

But newer versions (and some other VM implementations) throw this `Exception`:

```
java.util.FormatFlagsConversionMismatchException: Mismatched Convertor =s, Flags= #
        at java.util.Formatter$Transformer.transformFromString(Formatter.java:1020)
        at java.util.Formatter$Transformer.transform(Formatter.java:861)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:565)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:509)
        at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1961)
```

Any workarounds?

Comment: Which versions of Java does it work on, and which versions of Java does it fail on? Are you testing with the same data on each version (i.e. is it possible that the Java version is actually irrelevant and that it's actually certain inputs that produce the problem?)

Comment: yes. its the same data input in both the cases. Works all the time in Oracle JDK but fails in IBM jdk. others have reported the same cause - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SSHD-104

Comment: using jre-1.7.0_06, doesnt work. Works with 1.6.0_30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked for a workaround; just use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

```
public static String padLeft(String s, int n) {
    if (n <= 0)
        return s;
    int noOfSpaces = n * 2;
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(s.length() + noOfSpaces);
    while (noOfSpaces > 0) {
        output.append(" ");
        noOfSpaces--;
    }
    output.append(s);
    return output.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `#` flag in format string, you should pass [Formattable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formattable.html) as an argument ([doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)).

> Any work arounds?

Don't use `#` in format string?